# In Django www.example.com/?rcode=1 type url is not work

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am new in django and I am creating a referral url link that fills the referral input field when the link is open. This is my referral URL:

`https://hp30405.pythonanywhere.com/signup/?rcode=1`

But this is not fill input value where `name="rcode"`

this is my orignal page
`https://hp30405.pythonanywhere.com/signup/`

My project is in live. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you open the https://hp30405.pythonanywhere.com/signup/?rcode=1 url it wont directly fill your HTML input element you should manullly do that
just try this

```
{%if request.GET.rcode%}
<input type="hidden" name="rcode" value="{{request.GET.rcode}}"/>
{%endif%}
```

Comment: but sir in this method 1 problem if i use referal url this fill my refer code autometicaly but if i change the refer code manualy on this page it will got the refer code of autometicaly fill bu url how can i solve this                                                                                         if user change his refer code manualy then url also change

Comment: in that case remove if condition from outside and keep it inside value so that input element always exists like value="{%if request.GET.rcode%}{{request.GET.rcode}}{%endif%}" and when user change referal code update value using javascript

Comment: sir i am use this condition in javascript `if(request.GET.rcode != null){
          document.getElementById('rcode').value = request.GET.rcode;
      }` but this is not give any value in rcode field

Comment: {{request.GET.rcode}} its a django template variable

Comment: var rcode="{{request.GET.rcode}}"; then check rcode js variable